# Azure Service Bus: How to publish more than 256KB message to a Topic?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I am old school Windows Azure Architect. Using service bus topics to pass messages to worker role.

> How to publish more thank 256KB message to a subscription? I know
>   there is a premium tier service bus which allows 1MB message, but
>   1MB limit will may also not be enough.

Comment: One possibility would be to store the message content in blob storage and then save the blob URL as message.

Comment: @GauravMantri, This used to be our architecture earlier but due to high volume of messages being pumped-in we faced performance issues. We did not want IO blocking issues to happen. What other alternatives do we have?

Comment: > but again we're going to hit messaging limit. 
what does this mean?

Comment: @itaysk, thanks.. but 1MB limit will may also not be enough. because messages to be  posted to topics could be larger.

Comment: `This used to be our architecture earlier but due to high volume of messages being pumped-in we faced performance issues. We did not want IO blocking issues to happen.` -> Have you thought about fan-out approach? Instead of writing messages to  just one storage account, you write them to multiple storage accounts? That way you will not hit the performance thresholds for a single storage account.

Comment: @Abhijeet if the answer is not addressing your question, provide a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to send a **message** that is more than 256KB/1MB and avoid claim check pattern, then I'm questioning the design. ASB is about messaging, not data transfer.

The current ASB client (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) doesn't make claim check pattern implementation trivial, indeed. The good news is that with the new client (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) it's much simpler. You can leverage Extensions API and either use claim check pattern implementation provided by [`ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/servicebus.attachmentplugin) or extend it and allow multiple Storage accounts to be leveraged.

Comment: hi, why examples on github are not complete ? check first example about sending recieving, there is no line which send message.

Comment: @kosnkov, mind providing more details? What examples you're referring to? A link would help.